# Lining up label and input correctly

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a simple label, and a number input box:

[image]

The code for which is this:

```
<div id="total"><label>Total: <input type="tel" id="totalInput" onKeyUp="updateTotal()" /></label></div>
```

And css:

```
label {
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}

input {
    font-size: 16pt;
    left: auto;
    float:right;
    width: 60%;
}

#total {
    text-align:right;
}
```

But can't figure out how to move the word "Total:" down so that it is center-aligned (or otherwise looking well-aligned) to the input box.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the input's `font-size: 16pt` attribute to a `height: 16pt` attribute.
http://jsfiddle.net/GZLQy/

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for the `line-height` property of the text

```
class {
    ...
    line-height: 1.2;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `line-height` to move the label down

```
label {line-height: 1.5em;} //or there abouts
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a wild guess without a live demo (I actually never use labels that wrap the input element itself) but try adding `line-height:16pt` to your label selector.

```
label {
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    line-height:16pt;
}
```